# Nonnegative eigenvector form the point of view of variational characterization

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, eigenvalues, eigenvector

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ $(N\geq 3)$.  We denote by $G(x, y)$ the Green function for the boundary value problem
$$
-\Delta_x G(x, y)=c_n \delta(x-y) \quad \text { in } \Omega, \quad G(\cdot, y)=0 \quad \text { on } \partial \Omega,
$$
where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac mass at the origin and $c_n$ is the number such that
$$
-\Delta_x \Gamma(x)=c_n \delta(x), \quad \Gamma(x)=\alpha_n /|x|^{n-2},
$$
namely $c_n=(n-2) \omega_n \alpha_n$ with $\omega_n$ the surface area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\alpha_n$ the number in (1.7). We let $H(x, y)$ be the regular part of $G(x, y)$, namely the solution of the problem
$$
-\Delta_x H(x, y)=0 \quad \text { in } \Omega, \quad H(\cdot, y)=\Gamma(\cdot-y) \quad \text { in } \partial \Omega.
$$
The diagonal $H(x, x)$ is called the Robin function of $\Omega$. It is well known that
$$
H(x, x) \rightarrow \infty \quad \text { as } \operatorname{dist}(x, \partial \Omega) \rightarrow 0 .
$$

Let $q=\left(q_1, \ldots, q_k\right)$ be an array of $k$ distinct points in $\Omega$, and consider the $k \times k$ matrix
$$
\mathcal{G}(q)=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
H\left(q_1, q_1\right) & -G\left(q_1, q_2\right) & \ldots & & -G\left(q_1, q_k\right) \\
-G\left(q_1, q_2\right) & H\left(q_2, q_2\right) & -G\left(q_2, q_3\right) & \cdots & -G\left(q_3, q_k\right) \\
\vdots & & \ddots & & \vdots \\
-G\left(q_1, q_k\right) & \cdots & -G\left(q_{k-1}, q_k\right) & & H\left(q_k, q_k\right)
\end{array}\right]
$$
My question is   if $\gamma_1$ is the least eigenvalue of $\mathcal{G}(q)$, with eigenvector $v=\left(v_1, \ldots, v_k\right)$, how to prove that all its components of $v$ are nonnegative.(Here $\mathcal{G}(q)$ may  not be positively definite). This is taken from the paper [Green’s function and infinite-time bubbling in
the critical nonlinear heat equation, p295].  The hint from the paper is variational characterization. But I'm not sure how to deduce such result. Thank for any help.